# Part of the geometry disappears when in edit mode

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I need to seperate the bars from the cells in this model.
[image]

But when i go in the Edit Mode, the bars disappear.  I am using an array modifier, but I think the problem is not with the array.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a .blend file? Thanks!

Comment: This question and answer is better than in the one it's a duplicate of. Can we reverse the marking as duplicate so that that is a duplicate of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like you have *hidden* the bars.  To hide something, select it and press <kbd>H</kbd>.  If you are in object mode this will hide the *objects* that are selected, in edit mode this will hide only the *geometry* that is selected.  You can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide everything but the selection.

**To unhide everything, just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.**

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot. Now it works, thanks mate!

Comment: @CookieFresh Glad I could help!  If this solved your problem you can hit the *accept answer* button next to my answer.