# no faces in edit mode

Tags: modeling

I have been working on a complicated model for a long time and today it suddenly quit displaying faces in edit mode. It appears to be in wireframe, and toggling wireframe does not change that (unattached parts in my project toggle appropriately).  I looked at the object display settings and Textured is selected.  I tried selecting four vertices and creating a new face, but no face appears.  When I go to object mode, the faces appear normally.

This anomaly occurred out of the blue while I was working on the model.  I have not been importing or changing versions or otherwise manipulating the file.

[image]
A picture of my model in edit.  Note that the pants have faces; that is part of the larger model no longer showing faces.

My blend file:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a picture of your model when it appears to be in Wireframe mode while is in Texure instead? Has the object got any modifer (one above all Mask Modifier)?

Comment: Could it be that you've checked *Hidden Wire* option in Tools panel > *Shading* ?

Comment: I can't seem to find that option!  I googled it and they show it under the Materials->Shading panel, but it isn't there on my model.

Comment: I don't know how to post pictures.

Comment: It's in the [Tools panel](http://imgur.com/fhsXsga), which can be opened only in the 3D View (and shown there too). To add images to the post click "Edit" button in the bottom of it, click somewhere where'd you like to add it and press `Ctrl`+`G`; select image from your computer or internet.

Comment: No modifiers at all.

Comment: @Amanda about your other question, not a problem. You can use the "[edit](http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/43277/edit)" link below your post to edit any time.

Comment: As it's seen from screenshot, part of mesh (pants, which most likely are unconnected) has faces visible, while whole mesh doesn't, so this is definitely not *Hidden Wire* option used. Could you save that as a copy, delete almost everything except for small parts of body mesh and pants mesh and [upload a file here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) ?

Comment: I put a link to my file in the question:   http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/no-faces-in-edit-mode

Comment: I'm not sure how could that be done, but if you enter Edit mode and press `Alt`+`H` (reveal all hidden geometry) you'll get all Shiva's faces visible and editable. At the same time this definitely isn't a duplicate of linked question.

Comment: It's actually a duplicate of this one: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19469/part-of-the-geometry-disappears-when-in-edit-mode/19471#19471 which in turn is a duplicate of: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10576/missing-vertices-in-edit-mode/10578#10578

Comment: As noted by Mr Zak: Enter edit mode and press **Alt+H**: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SjhhZ.gif

Comment: @cegaton I'm still not sure it's a duplicate of questions you linked. The actions to repair are the same, that's true, while actions to get that behaviour which is in uploaded file are not. It won't work this way if just pressing `H` or `Shift`+`H` (correct me if this changed in latest builds). Tbh, I haven't ever seen such hiding faces only.

Comment: @MrZak you are right. If you select the faces and hide them the edges/vertices would disappear too.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the faces are not showing up is because they are hidden.

As [Mr Zak](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1245/mr-zak) suggested;

> Enter edit mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

This will reveal all hidden geometry.