# Why does my model turn into a mess when in object mode

Tags: texturing

Why does it do that when being in object mode?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modifiers are usually not visible in edit mode. Has your object any of them?

Comment: it had mirroring, but I applied it and it doesn't have any other one anymore

Comment: What about shape keys?

Comment: Nope, it has none

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/no-faces-in-edit-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no faces in edit mode](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/no-faces-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hidden faces

You have set some faces as not visible in edit mode. The fact that they are hidden is true only for edit mode; in object mode you'll see all the faces (unless you specifically  set up a mask modifier).

You can see the whole object by un-hiding the faces with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut while in edit mode.

Comment: yeah, I looked at the file to. ALT + H does the trick