# Hidden wire problem

Tags: modeling, wireframe

I'm using hidden wire on the properties panel while doing retopology work and sometimes I accidentally hit a shortcut key where get this:

[image]
Anyone know what is happening and what can I press to get back to the default display? So far all I can do to stop this is appending the object onto a new file.

Comment: Did u accidentally hit 'H' ? This is the shortcut for hiding selected entities. 'ALT+H' is used to unhide them.

Comment: Can you [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) a simplified copy of the file with problem part ? I don't think this can be caused by hiding geometry - if it hides faces it hides edges as well. If screenshot on the right shows only one object (and nothing beneath) then likely it's a bug, like [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/no-faces-in-edit-mode)

Comment: @Vectorius Just saw [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73745/mesh-is-disappearing-in-orthographic-view-is-there-in-perspective-view/73747#73747) today, and thought that maybe it was related to the same issue

Comment: Yes, its is the same problem, according to the comments it may be a bug

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not sure what key you're hitting to get that view (perhaps Z?) it looks like maybe your normals are not consistent. In edit mode, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals so all the faces are oriented correctly.

Comment: I thought so too, but its not, but CTRL+N does nothing