# Random Triangles sticking out of model?

Tags: modeling

Hey so I'm making a winchester rifle and on the butt theres this random triangle stick out of the side. I deleted the butt and it's still there. How do I get rid of this? Also it's only visible when your at the top angle however if you go under the model the problem disapears.  The question I am saying is how do i get rid of that triangle

[image]

Google Drive for the blend model: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PQkwASJvVsVLS1FkysBnseHo8WV9DcOa

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLnDy.png

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Welcome, Chemical. It is visible in the render?

Comment: Yes it is @LeoNas

Comment: Could you upload your blend file, or show different views of the gun while in edit mode?

Comment: Here you go: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PQkwASJvVsVLS1FkysBnseHo8WV9DcOa @RBlong2us

Comment: Ok, you had a triangle which was hidden in edit mode.  Simply hit Alt-H and you can see it.

Comment: I fucking love you

Comment: Possible duplication of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43277/no-faces-in-edit-mode